# javascript/jquery active link in nested submenus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to highlight the parent `li` element if a link is found either in one of the main `li` elements, or one of the nested lists for a header I'm working on. I feel like the JS should work, but it doesn't. Any pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/fGGrf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    $('.submenu-link').hover (function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('a').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }, function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('a').css('backgroundColor', 'white');
    });
```

**JSFiddle:**: http://jsfiddle.net/fGGrf/5/

Comment: Similar, but applying and keeping the change if the parent is the active page.

Comment: OK, then you need to make a CSS class which you toggle.

Comment: thanks I do have a .current class that I forgot to include in the fiddle. The issue is with the javascript to add it depending on if the href of the current page corresponds to something in either level of the menu, if that makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dropdown = $('.dropdown');
var link= $('.submenu-link');

var cur = "www.domain.com/overview.php" // document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;
cur = cur.split('/' , -1);

    $('li a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == '/' + cur[1]) {
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fGGrf/6/

Comment: This is very close, only instead of adding it to only the current link, it needs to be added to the top level li element

Comment: @kq9873 you can select the top level one with `$(this).closest('.parent').addClass('active');` http://jsfiddle.net/fGGrf/7/

Comment: jquery frustrates me to no end I went with this instead
     
    '$(function() {
  var current_page = win.location.pathname || '', path;
  $('a', '#nav').each(function(i, el) {
   path = ('/'+el.getAttribute('href')).replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/');
   if (path == current_page) {
    $(el).parents('.'+parent_class).first().addClass('active');
    return false;
   }
  });
 });'